# Django 4.2 create user model inside a models folder

Tags: django-models

I'm wanting to order the models in a Django app and the idea is this structure...

```
my_proyect
 |
 |---my_app
     |
     |---modelos
           |
           |---usuario.py (this file would have my custom user)
```

my questions are...

1. Would it be possible to have this structure in Django (ie the models are inside a subfolder)?
2. What do I need to change in settings.py for this to work (AUTH_USER_MODEL = '???' I don't know if this part would change anything).
3. Is there something else to change?